# Force tests to fail if migrations aren't run

Tags: django, django-migrations, pytest-django

I'm blatantly oblivious sometimes, and it led me down a 30 minute blackhole trying to figure out why my `constraints` weren't being applied in my tests. Turns out I forgot to run `makemigrations`. Is there a way to configure `pytest` or `django` to fail without `makemigrations`?

I know if very clearly warns me

```
Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
```

Just looking for something a little more obvious/in your face?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two commands will return an error if you have model changes not in migration files and if you have unapplied migrations respectively. You can run them as part of your test scripts

```
python manage.py makemigrations --check
python manage.py migrate --check
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-makemigrations-check
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-check